# finding date from pandas datetimeobject

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas object as follows:

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-06-12 00:00:00',infer_datetime_format = True)
```

I want to extract only the date from it.
Is there a built in for me to strip out only the date?

I tried `.dt.date` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use `dt` with Series. For a single Timestamp use `date()`:

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-06-12 00:00:00',infer_datetime_format = True).date()
```

output: `datetime.date(2022, 6, 12)`

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-06-12 00:00:00',infer_datetime_format = True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
'2022-06-12'
```